# tailwind - how to generate css as per particular version

Tags: css, tailwind-css

There is a package.json which is part of tailwind config/setup and is used to trigger the css generation engine, example below. the file references specific versions.

my quesion is - what are those version parameters used for and is it possible to keep to older version of tailwind engine? say i would like to stick to 3.1.8 and generate CSS as per that version instead of based on 3.2.4?

```
{
  "scripts": {

        "buildcss": "npx tailwindcss -i ./wwwroot/css/tailwind-source.css -o ./wwwroot/css/tailwind-destination.min.css --minify"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
        "postcss": "^8.4.21",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
      }
    }
```

i was not able to find anything on this in the tailwind documentation.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be referencing is snippet from a [`package.json` file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json). This file serves multiple purposes in the NPM/Node.js ecosystem, but for our purposes, the `devDependencies` (and `dependencies`) are, from [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies), "simple object that maps a package name to a version range."

Hence, if you would like to specify that you'd want version `3.1.8`, you could run:

```bash
npm install tailwindcss@3.1.8
```

This will update your `package.json` as well as your `package-lock.json` and also install `tailwindcss` version `3.1.8`.

Comment: hmm, i see, thanks for this! appreciate the time. what would be a potential purpose of this entry then: "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"

Comment: The `devDependencies` (and `dependencies`) are, from [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies), "simple object that maps a package name to a version range." Hence this entry maps the package name `tailwindcss` to the version range `^3.2.4`.